# Issue with Nodejs promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I have a sequence of function calls, connected with ES6 promises. Apparently, there is something wrong with this implementation, as API calls to the endpoint are not returning anything and the browser is stuck waiting for a response.

Please advise.

```
module.exports.insertTreatmentDetails = function (req, res) {
    var doctorId = 10000
    var departmentId = 10000
    var procedureid = 10000
    var hospitalSchema = new hospitalModel();

    var p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        counterSchema.getNext('Treatment.doctor.doctorId', collection, function (doctorId) {
            doctorId = doctorId;
        })
        counterSchema.getNext('Treatment.departmentId', collection, function (departmentId) {
            departmentId = departmentId
        })
        counterSchema.getNext('Treatment.procedureid', collection, function (procedureid) {
            procedureid = procedureid
        })
    }).then(function () {
        setData()
    }).then(function (){
        hospitalSchema.save(function (error, data) {
            if (error) {
                logger.error("Error while inserting record : - " + error)
                return res.json({ "Message": error.message.split(":")[2].trim() });
            }
            else {
                return res.json({ "Message": "Data got inserted successfully" });
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: You don't have a `catch` on the Promise... if there is an Error anywhere in there, you would never know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you aren't calling `resolve` or `reject` inside the first promise in your chain. The promise remains in a `pending` state. Mozilla has a good [basic explanation of promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

**How to Fix**

It appears that you want to retrieve `doctorId`, `departmentId`, and `procedureId` before calling `setData`. You could try to wrap all three calls in one promise, checking whether all three have returned something in each callback, but the ideal is to have one promise per asynchronous task.

If it's feasible to alter `counterSchema.getNext`, you could have that function return a promise instead of accepting a callback. If not, I would recommend wrapping each call in its own promise. To keep most true to what your code currently looks like, that could look like this:

```
const doctorPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
    counterSchema.getNext('Treatment.doctor.doctorId', collection, id => {
        doctorId = id;
        resolve();
    }));
```

Then you could replace the first promise with a call to `Promise.all`:

```
var p = Promise.all([doctorPromise, departmentPromise, procedurePromise])
    .then(setData)
    .then(/* ... */);
```

Promises allow you to pass a value through to the next step, so if you wanted to get rid of your broadly-scoped variables (or set them in the same step where you call `setData`), you could just pass `resolve` as your callback to `counterSchema.getNext` and collect the values in the next step (also how you'd want to do it if you have `counterSchema.getNext` return a promise:

```
Promise.all([/* ... */])
    .then(([doctorID, departmentID, procedureID]) => {
        // If you aren't changing `setData`
        doctorId = doctorID;
        departmentId = departmentID;
        procedureid = procedureID;
        setData();
        // If you are changing `setData`
        setData(doctorID, departmentID, procedureID);
    }).then(/* ... */).catch(/* I would recommend adding error handling */);
```

Comment: How do i return a value to response object?Looks like the way i return value to response obejct is not working

Comment: `new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {` is creating a promise.  The function inside is given two more functions it can call: `resolve` and `reject`.  Calling `resolve` resolves the promise, and the next `.then` is gone to.  Calling `reject` causes the promise to reject, and the next `.catch` is found.  You weren't calling `resolve`.

Comment: Thanks for the brilliant explanation Brett.Hope this will help many new bees to understand promise

Comment: Don't set a global variable. Pass the result into the `resolve` call.

Comment: That's what I was trying to imply with `// If you are changing setData`.  Is there a good way to make that more clear?